# Compiz crashes when using hot corners on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, 16.10, unity-tweak-tool

When using Unity Tweaks to enable and configure hot corners, moving the cursor to a corner to activate it crashes Compiz.

I first noticed this in 16.04, and it's still the case after I upgraded to 16.10.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

I was only able to get my desktop usable again after restarting Compiz from the terminal.